# When can an empty array be iterated over?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Defining arrays in javascript using Array(n) defines an empty array, please correct me if I am wrong. Now if I write the below code:

```js
Array(2).map((val) => console.log(val))
```

.. nothing happens, but when I spread out the elements of the array into an other array, like so:

```js
[...Array(2)].map((val) => console.log(val))
```

.. I get undefined console logs. Can anyone please help me understand what is happening here ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without spreading, the array is simply an object with a `length` property, with no items populated:

> { length: 2, **proto**: Array(0) }

When you spread (`...`) into an array, if the object you're spreading has a `length` property, it will spread that many items, starting from `obj[0]`, `obj[1]`, etc. The object in question doesn't actually need to have those numeric properties - if it doesn't, then the result of the spreading will be an array of `undefined`s:

```js
console.log([...Array(2)]);
```

An array of `undefined`s *can* be iterated over - here, the indicies `0` and `1` *do* exist in the array object, they just happen to not be assigned to anything.

```js
const arr = [undefined, undefined];
console.log(1 in arr);
```

So, in short, it's because the difference between an array such as

```
{ length: 2 } // no elements to iterate over
```

and

```
{ length: 2, 0: undefined, 1: undefined }
```

Note that you shouldn't use `map` if you're not using the transformed array that `.map` returns - otherwise, if you just want to iterate over each item and `console.log` it, for example, you should use `forEach`.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) takes the iterable's length, then iterates over the passed value ([See spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-arrayaccumulation)).

Since all *returned* valued from iterating over `Array(2)` are undefined, your second line `map`s over `[undefined, undefined]`, while your fist line maps over `[empty x 2]`. Note that "empty" aren't actual values.

`map` doesn't iterate over "empty" entries, like those created by `Array(2)`, but does iterate over `undefined` values:

> [image]

Comment: Then why `console.log(Array(4).map(val => val))` works ?

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut: It doesn't. `Array(4).map(val => {console.log(1)})`. `.map` does not iterate over non-existant entries. You won't see that `1` being logged. In a way, `.map` is "smarter" than the spread syntax, as `.map`.

Comment: When i use `console.log(Array(4).map(val => val))` I receive an array `[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]`

Comment: ... That's not what the spec says it should return. Both Chrome and Firefox _return_ an Array of 4 empty slots. Both don't log anything else. What browser are you using, @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut? Is it also logging the `1` 4 times?

Comment: No, it's not logging the `1` 4 times.

Comment: What browser are you using, @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome browser.

Comment: What version? What OS?

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut i think you may be mistaken, maybe you slipped a .fill() in between `Array(4)` and `map(...)` (`console.log(Array(4).fill().map(val => val))
`)?  `console.log(Array(4).map(val => val))` gives me `(4) [empty × 4]` on chrome

Answer (score 1):

Because `Array(2)` doesn't populate the array. But it does set the length property to 2. So in the first instance, `map` has nothing to iterate over. But the destructuring creates an array of 2 elements of `undefined`, which allows map to work since `undefined` is a valid primitive.

Answer (score 0):

This is how Array.map works - please read here: [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned
>   values, including undefined. It is not called for missing elements of
>   the array (that is, indexes that have never been set, which have been
>   deleted or which have never been assigned a value).